# Axios Get Request Not Working with Json Array Object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to fetch second [1] item's title from an object array in JSON:

```
{
    "@attributes": {
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    "channel": {
        "title": "Rust News",
        "description": "The latest news posts from Rust",
        "lastBuildDate": "Thu, 07 Jul 2022 07:00:00 Z",
        "item": [
            {
                "guid": "https:\/\/rust.facepunch.com\/news\/july-2022-update\/",
                "link": "https:\/\/rust.facepunch.com\/news\/july-2022-update\/",
                "title": "July Update",
                "description": "<img src=\"https:\/\/files.facepunch.com\/paddy\/20220705\/july_2022_header.jpg\"><br\/>Combat balance, faster load times, chat filter and much more!\u00a0\u00a0",
                "pubDate": "Thu, 07 Jul 2022 07:00:00 Z"
            },
            {
                "guid": "https:\/\/rust.facepunch.com\/news\/community-update-243\/",
                "link": "https:\/\/rust.facepunch.com\/news\/community-update-243\/",
                "title": "Community Update 243",
                "description": "<img src=\"https:\/\/files.facepunch.com\/errn\/1b1311b1\/FTTfqglWQAMxkzD.jpg\"><br\/>Custom desk mats, Mars monuments, thoughtful poetry, and more!",
                "pubDate": "Wed, 15 Jun 2022 12:00:00 Z"
            }
...
```

Here is the axios code:

```
  mounted() {
    this.axios.get("./api/feedRust.php").then(response => {
        this.items = response.data.channel;
    });
  }
```

Everything works as expected when tusing **response.data.channel**, however unable to fetch any object from item array due to this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
```

HTML/Vuejs code:

```
<div>{{items.item[1].title}}<div>
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you defined data with the property, because while fetching the response data, it will try to access the `items.item`, which may not exists with the `index`.

Add the conditional statement.

Like this:

```
<div v-if="items.item && items.item.length > 1">{{items.item[1].title}}<div>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure why since the condition only checks if the property is defined and has more than one object (right?), but works like a charm now, thank you!